# the text is out of the div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following issue, if I minimize the browser width, the spans are out of the div:[image]

How can I change the line automatically (without using br)? Like:
[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="bg-danger col-12 col-md-4 col-xl-3 p-5 mb-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-start flex-column">
          <span>pepasdasdsadaiadtoadsasdasssssssda23@gmail.com</span>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-start flex-column">
          <span>pepasdasdsadaiadtoadsasdasssssssda23@gmail.com</span>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i need it with col-xl-3, col-12 is when screen is <576px, if i remove it, problem stills

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `word-break: break-all` CSS property.

```css
.break-words {word-break: break-all}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="bg-danger col-12 col-md-4 col-xl-3 p-5 mb-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-start flex-column break-words">
          <span>pepasdasdsadaiadtoadsasdasssssssda23pepasdasdsadaiadtoadsasdasssssssda23@gmail.com</span>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-start flex-column">
          <span>pepasdasdsadaiadtoadsasdasssssssda23@gmail.com</span>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the CSS property on the span `word-wrap: break-word;`